# How BatchToSpaceND actually works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to figure out how [BatchToSpaceND](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/batch_to_space_nd) permutes the input matrix. One of the examples is the following:

> (3) For the following input of shape [4, 2, 2, 1] and block_size of 2:
>
> ```
> x = [[[[1], [3]], [[9], [11]]],
>      [[[2], [4]], [[10], [12]]],
>      [[[5], [7]], [[13], [15]]],
>      [[[6], [8]], [[14], [16]]]]
> ```
>
> The output tensor has shape [1, 4, 4, 1] and value:
>
> ```
> x = [[[1],   [2],  [3],  [4]],
>      [[5],   [6],  [7],  [8]],
>      [[9],  [10], [11],  [12]],
>      [[13], [14], [15],  [16]]]
> ```

Anyone know how the output tensor is derived? How come the first row is `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` and not `[[1], [3], [9], [11]]` instead? I've also tried some code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = [[[[1], [3]], [[9], [11]]],
     [[[2], [4]], [[10], [12]]],
     [[[5], [7]], [[13], [15]]],
     [[[6], [8]], [[14], [16]]]]
b = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
a = tf.reshape(a, b)

b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
a = tf.reshape(a, b)

b = [1, 4, 4, 1]
a = tf.reshape(a, b)

print(a.eval())

[[[[ 1]
   [ 3]
   [ 9]
   [11]]

  [[ 2]
   [ 4]
   [10]
   [12]]

  [[ 5]
   [ 7]
   [13]
   [15]]

  [[ 6]
   [ 8]
   [14]
   [16]]]]
```

which isn't quite the result in the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the argument's section of [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/batch_to_space_nd#args):

> `input`: A `Tensor`. N-D with shape `input_shape = [batch] + spatial_shape + remaining_shape`, where `spatial_shape` has `M` dimensions.

So for the specific example this means we have batch dimension `4`, spatial shape `(2, 2)` and remaining shape `(1,)`. It is instructive to consider a real world example here. Let's think of this input tensor as a batch of four 2x2 images with 1 channel (e.g. grayscale). Since the operation does not modify the `remaining_shape` we can neglect it for the further exploration. That is the input contains effectively the following 2x2 "images":

```
 1   3
 9  11
--------
 2   4
10  12
--------
 5   7
13  15
--------
 6   8
14  16
```

Now what the operation asks for is to reshape the batch dimension into spatial dimensions, similar to reshaping a one dimensional array `a` of size `batch` into `a.reshape(-1, *block_shape)`. If we consider the batch indices `[0, 1, 2, 3]` they will be reshaped into `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]` (omitting the new size 1 batch dimension). Effectively this means we should take the four 2x2 images and place them side by side, where `block_shape` indicates the layout, in order to create one 4x4 image. At this point however we're not done yet as one additional step remains, namely the spatial dimensions are interleaved, as indicated by the documentation:

> This operation reshapes the "batch" dimension 0 into `M + 1` dimensions of shape `block_shape + [batch]`, **interleaves these blocks back into the grid defined by the spatial dimensions `[1, ..., M]`**, to obtain a result with the same rank as the input.

That is laying out the images in the grid we have:

```
 1   3     2   4
 9  11    10  12

 5   7     6   8
13  15    14  16
```

Now we are left with interleaving the row and column dimensions of the individual images in order to arrive at the final result:

```
        -------⅂
       |       |
    -------⅂   |
   |   |   |   |
   v   v   |   |

 1   3     2   4
                  <---⅂
 9  11    10  12      |
                  <---|---⅂
                      |   |
                      |   |
 5   7     6   8   ---⅃   |
                          |
13  15    14  16   -------⅃
```

Which gives:

```
 1   2     3   4
 5   6     7   8
 9  10    11  12
13  14    15  16
```

The actual output from the example has shape `(1, 4, 4, 1)` as it contains the additional `remaining_shape` (which we've omitted for the sake of the example) and it retains the batch dimension (which is 1 in this case).

### Equivalent code example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = np.array([[[[1], [3]], [[ 9], [11]]],
              [[[2], [4]], [[10], [12]]],
              [[[5], [7]], [[13], [15]]],
              [[[6], [8]], [[14], [16]]]])

block_shape = (2, 2)

new_batch_size = a.shape[0] // np.prod(block_shape)
b = tf.reshape(a, 
    block_shape
    + (new_batch_size,)
    + a.shape[1:]
)
# Hard-coded version:
# b = tf.transpose(b, [2, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5])
# Generic version:
b = tf.transpose(b,
    (len(block_shape),)
    + tuple(j for i in range(len(block_shape)) for j in (i + len(block_shape) + 1, i))
    + tuple(i + 2*len(block_shape) + 1 for i in range(len(a.shape) - len(block_shape) - 1))
)
b = tf.reshape(b,
    (new_batch_size,)
    + tuple(i*j for i, j in zip(block_shape, a.shape[1:]))
    + a.shape[1+len(block_shape):]
)
print(b.eval())
print(b.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. After the first reshape, what is the new shape? The doc says `[block_shape[0], ..., block_shape[M-1], batch / prod(block_shape), input_shape[1], ..., input_shape[N-1]]` but it's not clear what `prod(block_shape)` means. Assuming it's product, is the new shape `[2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]`? That's probably a bit too many dimensions.

Comment: @Kar Considering an equivalent sequence of tensorflow operations, as outlined in the docs, does actually yield a tensor of shape `[2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]` after step 1 (the first reshape). This is then followed by a permutation of axes, while in your code example you've used another reshape which doesn't yield the same result. In the actual implementation however I'm sure they used a more efficient implementation, avoiding these extra dimensions and directly assigning to the resulting tensor of shape `[1, 4, 4, 1]` (I don't have the link to the source at hand though). Please see my updated answer.